# EPPlus - ExcelWorksheet object getting null when assigning to another object

Tags: c#, winforms, epplus

I updated EPPlus version 3.1.3.0 to 4.1.1 in my C# Winform application and getting subject issue. Same code working fine in previous version.

Below is my code which reads Excel file and get sheet by Name with below code.

[image]

Above code works fine and sheet data comes in "item" object like following:

[image]

But once I assign "item" ExcelWorksheet object to another ExcelWorksheet object to return it to calling method so its internal members getting null.

like following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed the issue.

Following line was creating issue in new version of EPPlus:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
```

In new version of EPPlus, package object must not be disposed in order to read Worksheet. So I removed using and it works fine now.